# How to get an ordered list of rows within 0 value with sql?

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM atable ORDER BY num;
```

'atable' is:

```
num  name     
1     a    
3     y    
0     cc    
2     fs
```

The result is:

```
num  name     
1     a    
2     fs    
3     y    
0     cc
```

But I want it to be:

```
num  name  
0     cc    
1     a    
2     fs    
3     y
```

Comment: can you please post your table definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the result you are seeing. The query that you posted should work as you wish it to. Here's my steps to reproduce:

```
CREATE TABLE atable (num INT NOT NULL, name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO atable (num, name) VALUES
(1, 'a'),
(3, 'y'),
(0, 'cc'),
(2, 'fs');
SELECT * FROM atable ORDER BY num;
```

Result:

```
0, 'cc'
1, 'a'
2, 'fs'
3, 'y'
```

Perhaps you could post your create scripts for your table and test data in your question so that we can reproduce your result?

Comment: suspect posters 'num' column is not an int

Comment: For completeness, could the OP explain how this answers his question?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the 0 isn't a null value being displayed as a 0?  Nulls can sort either at the top or the bottom, depending on database setting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM atable 
ORDER BY ISNULL(CAST(num as int), 0);
```

Comment: A char value of '0' will still sort before a char value of '1'